# Why is it happening?

Tags: python, numpy, input, numbers, root

So, I've started a program to calculate the nth root of a number:

```
*x = float(input('Enter a number: '))
n = float(input('Enter the root you would like to calculate: '))
result=x**(1/float(n))
print(f'The {n}th root of = {x} is:',result)*
```

The program works with every number and root, but when I enter as x=64 and n=3 it shows this:
***The 3.0 root of = 64.0 is: 3.9999999999999996***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in comments, this is the nature of [floating point math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

In your case, you can control what you print with a specifier in an f-string:

```
>>> n = 3.999996
>>> print(f"{n : .0f}")
 4
>>>
```

Answer (score -2):

Its because of the way floating point is stored. Often you'll see stuff like this, a solution is to always round result to the nearest like, thousandth.